# How to do --rm and --restart in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When you run docker run you have the option to add --rm and --restart. But how do you get the same effect in a dockerfile?

Answer (score 9):

Dockerfile is used to specify instructions to build an image.

Once the image is built, you can start a container from that image using `docker run` command. `--rm` and `--restart` are options for `docker run`, which means those commands apply to a container. Using the `--restart` flag you can specify a restart policy for a container. `--rm` flag is used to remove the file system on the container when it exits.

I hope you can see why the functionality provided by those two flags doesn't belong in the Dockerfile. If not, you should really read more about Docker (esp. images vs containers).

ADDITION:

`--rm` removes the file system and cleans up the container. `restart` is used only to restart a container, and the file system disappearing between restarts would be extremely unpleasant. Also note that a restart after file system removal is more like a "fresh start" than a "restart". So basically they're mutually exclusive. Using them together will result in an error. Doesn't matter where you do it.

Comment: Alright, but how would I then do --rm in a docker-compose.yml? I know there is the restart command but what about --rm?

Comment: @J.Eng Updated n=my answer.

Comment: There are situations in which a file system disappearing between restarts would be very desirable.  For instance, a server container that is supposed to be stateless but happens to write scratch files to disk.  If it crashes, you may want to have that clear out automatically.  It's obviously context dependent, but a fresh start after a crash is often a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

`--rm` and `--restart` can not be defined in a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). The options are also mutually exclusive. `docker run` only allows one or the other to be used.

A [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) file allows you to set the [`restart`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/cpushares-cpuquota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-macaddress-memlimit-memswaplimit-oomscoreadj-privileged-readonly-restart-shmsize-stdinopen-tty-user-workingdir) option for containers. Container removal though, is more of a lifecycle event of other compose commands like [`up --build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), [`down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) and [`rm`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/) rather than something you assign to a container.

Comment: So it is not possible to have --rm in a docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

```
--rm  Automatically remove the container when it exits
--restart string   Restart policy to apply when a container exits (default "no")
Possible values are : no, on-failure[:max-retry], always, unless-stopped
```

a example to user docker maven

```
docker run \
--rm \
-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 \
-v /my/java/proj:/usr/src/mymaven \
-w /usr/src/mymaven \
maven:3.3.3-jdk-8 mvn clean package
```